# Best "identifying markers" in code which help quick navigation to a certain location in code?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

In a class with 750+ lines, it is very time consuming to scroll through the code searching a specific method. when you're not the author of the code, wasted time multiplies.

What techniques do you use when you need to quickly jump to a specific method? Remember, it's not your code and you cannot memorize method name. You also cannot jump to a specific line as it's hard to memorize line numbers.

I use two approaches, which are the best I came up to.

1. *I set a breakpoint at some method*. Pro: visually appealing, Con: irritating when debugging and mixes with the "real" breakpoints
2. *I set //TODO marker at some method*. Pro: easy to navigate via Todo list. Con: mixes with "real" todo tasks and increases possibility to oversee some task

Please advise...

Comment: Is there something wrong with the Structure tab in IntelliJ?

Comment: wont eclipse just list all the methods in the "outline" tab at the side?

Comment: @Anonymoose I wasn't aware of that tab. I'll see it now. Thanks

Comment: @Jacxel I wasn't aware of that tab. I'll see it now. Thanks

Comment: @Anonymoose Too many things appear and I still have to memorize all the methods. But definitely faster than scrolling.

Comment: *"I'll see it now."*  'A picture' like the IDE on-screen paints a thousand words, yet it took 2 single sentence comments for you to notice these things?

Comment: @AndrewThompson You're not right. Structure tab is not default on in IntelliJ IDEA. I just realized it now.

Comment: @Anonymoose Any other cool trick on this? Thanks for Structure tab. It wasn't shown by default.

Comment: Ctrl-F12 - popup structure thingy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the things IJ does best.

ctrl-click/ctrl-b: jump to definition from its usage (you should be using this constantly)

Structure View (Alt-7) combined with the structure view button which says "Scroll From Source"

ctrl-shift-left/right: move between previous cursor locations edit location

ctrl-alt-shift-N: find any symbol by name. Even if you dont know that much of the name. You can use wild cards, and camel case, or leave it all lowercase and perform case insensitive search.

Alt-F6 : find usages of element at caret. (Show me where this API is being used)

Bookmarks, they work like your breakpoints and todos, except their intended purpose matches your needs - are all visually different and support quick keyboard navigation.